# How do I filter cards by person in Trello?

Tags: trello

In Trello, I would like to only see cards assigned to a specific person.

Is there a way to filter this view?

Answer (score 5):

Trello has added [card filtering](https://trello.com/card/board/card-filtering/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e7224d1ba71ca0000044974)!

Comment: There's no need to make the answers Community Wiki.

Comment: This feature has been deployed.

Comment: this doesn't work for filter all my cards from different boards, nor all cards by an organization

Comment: This board is not publically accessible.